# Data from database to JList

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I created a database, in which one of the table name is Location which has 2 columns named Stadium and City. I want that data in each column should get retrieved in 2 JList, but I don't know how. Can you guys tell me how to do it?

Comment: You don't know how to retrieve the data from the database? You don't know how to build `JList`s? Where exactly do you want us to start? What have you tried? What are stuck on?

Comment: i know how to retrieve data from JList, but don't know how to retrieve it in JList..

Comment: Then I'd suggest you need to visit the link that Robin has provided. It will give you head start with what you need. If you have any specific questions about anything contained within the tuts, then please feel free to ask another question

Comment: SO is not a code factory.  You seem to be confused about that.

Answer (score 2):

The normal way to display a table from a database is of course a `JTable`. But if you want to opt for 2 `JList`s instead, it is basically the same principle.

Create a model based on the contents of the database (in this case a `ListModel`). You can probably just extend from `AbstractListModel`. Once you have your model, it is trivial to create a `JList` for it by just passing the model in the constructor.

See the [*How to use lists*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) tutorial and pay special attention on the *Creating a model* part of that tutorial

Comment: @RohanSinghDhaka the linked tutorial contains plenty of examples

Comment: +1 for using the model. `AbstractListModel` will be more flexible, but `DefaultListModel`, shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7620726/230513) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2937338/230513), may serve.